# Why does building from a docker file take up all the disk space?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I am using docker-compose to build and run my application.

here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: sh startup.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx 
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

So, when I go to the command line and do `docker-compose up` it just sort of stays there saying `Building web...` for a long time then finally finishes with the error saying that it has run out of space. The vagrant vm has 40gb so i am not sure what would cause all of that space to be taken up.

```
Pulling db (postgres:latest)...
latest: Pulling from postgres

902b87aaaec9: Pull complete
9a61b6b1315e: Pull complete
26a84c436db4: Pull complete
22ed955cce18: Pull complete
8b6b2a3b7f9c: Pull complete
c783ebe7a1d4: Pull complete
e07b5a739ed9: Pull complete
0b82f508e063: Pull complete
02fa71f1fa38: Pull complete
b41b53da5fba: Pull complete
49915906faae: Pull complete
a814508841fa: Pull complete
64957633c267: Pull complete
a95070c23e86: Pull complete
c5d75e7f9094: Pull complete
3fa84fbfdec9: Pull complete
39172f8b90f2: Pull complete
09e02a9f8afe: Pull complete
4df8a54cf33a: Pull complete
3e840dbb5474: Pull complete
730d1d72bda2: Already exists
postgres:latest: The image you are pulling has been verified. Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.

Digest: sha256:66ba100bc635be1746daadd3ecfa46b51fbb767cd9fbc170edbf33483010065b
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
Creating webapp_db_1...
Building web...
Step 0 : FROM python:2.7
2.7: Pulling from python
1ff9f26f09fb: Pull complete
607e965985c1: Pull complete
9213e81cb0f2: Pull complete
0a18b31a754d: Pull complete
894736a966eb: Pull complete
169a877759a5: Pull complete
4d661b41bfe3: Pull complete
0c69eb1a3057: Pull complete
c5942c48e4c6: Pull complete
76e439c97b9c: Pull complete
e1857ee1f3b5: Already exists
902b87aaaec9: Already exists
9a61b6b1315e: Already exists
python:2.7: The image you are pulling has been verified. Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.
Digest: sha256:958cf6cce0a123875b9d04598a1927d92becc5cc0dae9bd5cf26ec821e2eda32
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:2.7
 ---> e1857ee1f3b5
Step 1 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Running in daf17fb52804
 ---> 32f372e41634
Removing intermediate container daf17fb52804
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
 ---> Running in aa1170c05965
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease [134 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [157 kB]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [123 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9038 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [3616 B]
Fetched 9519 kB in 8s (1155 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcdt5 libcgraph6 libcroco3
  libdjvulibre-dev libelfg0 libexif-dev libexif12 libexpat1-dev
  libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-bin
  libgraphviz-dev libgvc6 libgvpr2 libice-dev libice6 libilmbase-dev
  libjasper-dev libjbig-dev libjs-excanvas libjs-jquery liblcms2-dev
  liblqr-1-0-dev liblzo2-2 libmagickcore-6-arch-config libmagickcore-6-headers
  libmagickwand-6-headers libopenexr-dev libpathplan4 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsm-dev libsm6 libtiff5-dev libtiffxx5 libwmf-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxdot4 libxext-dev libxrender-dev libxt-dev libxt6
  mime-support pkg-config x11-common x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev xorg-sgml-doctools
  xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  geoip-database init-system-helpers libgeoip1 nginx-common nginx-full
Suggested packages:
  geoip-bin fcgiwrap nginx-doc ssl-cert
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  geoip-database init-system-helpers libgeoip1 nginx nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 2210 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6860 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libgeoip1 amd64 1.6.2-4 [90.8 kB]
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main init-system-helpers all 1.22 [14.0 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main geoip-database all 20150317-1 [1517 kB]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main nginx-common all 1.6.2-5 [86.6 kB]
Get:5 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main nginx-full amd64 1.6.2-5 [429 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main nginx all 1.6.2-5 [72.1 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 2210 kB in 2s (829 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libgeoip1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 18873 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgeoip1_1.6.2-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgeoip1:amd64 (1.6.2-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package init-system-helpers.
Preparing to unpack .../init-system-helpers_1.22_all.deb ...
Unpacking init-system-helpers (1.22) ...
Selecting previously unselected package geoip-database.
Preparing to unpack .../geoip-database_20150317-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking geoip-database (20150317-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-common.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.6.2-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.6.2-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-full.
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-full_1.6.2-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-full (1.6.2-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/nginx_1.6.2-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.6.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
Setting up libgeoip1:amd64 (1.6.2-4) ...
Setting up init-system-helpers (1.22) ...
Setting up geoip-database (20150317-1) ...
Setting up nginx-common (1.6.2-5) ...
Setting up nginx-full (1.6.2-5) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up nginx (1.6.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u1) ...
 ---> b0c936818d0d
Removing intermediate container aa1170c05965
Step 3 : RUN mkdir /code
 ---> Running in cb513ddbaf65
 ---> c1cc5a5da673
Removing intermediate container cb513ddbaf65
Step 4 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Running in d9ea2fb9e550
 ---> 059962be4b7d
Removing intermediate container d9ea2fb9e550
Step 5 : ADD requirements.txt /code/
 ---> fc1f1f9d63b9
Removing intermediate container 4380a58aef2d
Step 6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in e9db31e110aa
Collecting boto (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading boto-2.38.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Collecting django-storages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading django-storages-1.1.8.tar.gz
Collecting Django (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading Django-1.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
Collecting psycopg2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: django-storages, psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-storages
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/11/36/48/600ce18487aa34307973cf27d3004067f213dbba9df82e77c8
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e2/9a/5e/7b620848bbc7cfb9084aafea077be11618c2b5067bd532f329
Successfully built django-storages psycopg2
Installing collected packages: boto, django-storages, Django, psycopg2
Successfully installed Django-1.8.3 boto-2.38.0 django-storages-1.1.8 psycopg2-2.6.1
 ---> f64bc27b721e
Removing intermediate container e9db31e110aa
Step 7 : ADD . /code/
Service 'web' failed to build: Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: write /code/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_fusion/b2b99ae2-136e-4f62-96cc-d562e4867f09/disk-s007.vmdk: no space left on device
```

Does anyone know what is initially taking the `Building web...` step so long? Or why It would take up all the space on the machine. I am only installing a few packages and pip libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you begin with a `mkdir xxx ; cd xxx` before creating your Dockerfile?

I suppose you had a message "uploading context".

Extract from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2342   "the client is tar/compressing the directory (and all subdirectories) where you executed docker build. Yeah, that's right. If you execute this in your root directory, your whole drive will get tar'd and sent to the docker daemon. "

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this by just putting all docker related files in to it's own directory so that it would not compress all the unneeded files. I think it was going in to some sort of loop when compressing the .vagrant file.